# TypeError: posts.map is not a function (next.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

it's my first asking here. I hope, someone can help me:

It's simple app with using Next.js and while watching first tutorial video i had this problem:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: posts.map is not a function

Source
pages\posts\index.tsx (16:23) @ map

  14 |     <h1>Posts</h1>
  15 |     <div>
> 16 |         {posts.map((item) =>
     |               ^
  17 |             <div>{item.title}</div>)}
  18 |     </div>
  19 | </div>
```

1. Whole code(index.tsx):

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getAllPosts, Post} from "@/services/post";

export default function Main() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Post[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllPosts()
            .then((data) => setPosts(data))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            <div>
                {posts.map((item) =>
                    <div>{item.title}</div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

2. post.ts:

```
import { API_URL} from "@/services/index";  //(from index.ts where path to API)

export interface Post {
    userId: number,
    id: number,
    title: string,
    body: string
}

export async function getAllPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/posts`)
    return await response.json()
}

export async function getOnePost(id: number): Promise<Post> {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}`)
    return await response.json()
}
```

I think, problem with a key, but i don't know, how and where i can use this in .map()

Comment: The problem is that your API doesn't return an array

Comment: Oh, thank u very much! I find a problem, i just write incorrect path to API and now feel shamefull that i lost a lot of time on this. Anyways, thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with API:

I wrote

```
export const API_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'
```

Instead of

```
export const API_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
```

Be carefull with this ;)